# Condionar WHERE con un Subselect - SQL

Tags: sql

No logro mostrar las requisiciones que tienen su estado en NULL.

Query principal que trae las requisiciones asociadas a "X" datos:

```
SELECT
re.[codigo] AS codigo_requisicion
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Requisicion] AS re 
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Distribucion_Requisicion] AS dr 
ON dr.[idRequisicion] = re.[idRequisicion]
LEFT JOIN [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[PURCHTABLE] as ptNu 
ON ptNu.REQATTENTION = re.[codigo]
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Orden_Compra] as oc 
ON oc.[numero_documento] = ptNu.PURCHID
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Documento_Orden_Compra] as doc 
ON doc.[idOrdenCompra] = oc.[idOrdenCompra]
order by re.[fecha_emision] desc
```

hasta aca todo bien.

luego quiero mostrar el  `estado` en el cual se encuentra la requisicion, aplico un `subselect` para traer el estado y quedaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT
re.[codigo] AS codigo_requisicion,
(
SELECT e.[nombre]
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
AND red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = (SELECT MAX(red.idEtapaTipoDocumento) 
            FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Etapa_Documento] AS red
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa_Tipo_Documento] AS etd 
            ON etd.[idEtapaTipoDocumento] = red.[idEtapaTipoDocumento]
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Etapa] AS e 
            ON e.[idEtapa] = etd.[idEtapa]
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Registro_Documento] AS rd 
            ON rd.[idRegistroDocumento] = red.[idRegistroDocumento]
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura] AS fa 
            ON fa.[idFactura] = rd.[idDocumento]
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Factura_Orden_Compra] AS fo 
            ON fo.[idFactura] = fa.[idFactura]
            INNER JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Tipo_Documento] AS td 
            ON td.[idTipoDocumento] = rd.[idTipoDocumento]
            WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(13), fo.[orden_compra]) = oc.[numero_documento]
            and red.[recepcionado]='1')
) AS estado
FROM [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Requisicion] AS re 
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Distribucion_Requisicion] AS dr 
ON dr.[idRequisicion] = re.[idRequisicion]
LEFT JOIN [MSAXPRODG4].[dbo].[PURCHTABLE] as ptNu 
ON ptNu.REQATTENTION = re.[codigo]
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Orden_Compra] as oc 
ON oc.[numero_documento] = ptNu.PURCHID
LEFT JOIN [Control_Documental].[dbo].[Documento_Orden_Compra] as doc 
ON doc.[idOrdenCompra] = oc.[idOrdenCompra]
ORDER BY re.[fecha_emision] desc
```

Hasta aca todo bien, me muestra la requisicion y su estado, cabe mencionar que hay requisiciones que no tienen un estado asociado, por ende muestra este dato en null o vacio.

[image: REQ]

mi problema es el siguiente, ahora necesito trar las requisiciones que no tienen un estado asociado, o que su estado esta en `NULL`, debiera mostrar solo esto:

[image: REQ]

Entonces al condicionar mi Query principal :
`WHERE estado IS NULL` me arrojar error `invalid column name` o si condiciono por `WHERE e.[nombre] IS NULL` me arroja error `the multi part identifier e.[nombre] could not be found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, primero que todo, debo decir que deberían encontrar una forma más simple de buscar el estado de una requisicion.

Ahora bien, para lograr lo que quieres (y sin intervenir tu código actual) debes simplemente usar una tabla derivada:

```
SELECT *
FROM ("poner tu consulta actual acá") t
WHERE estado IS NULL;
```

Comment: Lamentablemente es un BD que no esta normalizada, por ende es muy complicado llegar al dato. probare como me indicas y te respondo.

Comment: intente como me mencionas y la consulta queda en `Ejecutando Consulta...` no trae error, ni tampoco respuesta. 
existira alguna forma de condicionar el `codigo_requisicion` para que traiga solo estos que tienen estados nulos?

Comment: gracias, mi query la modifique, y si me sirvio tu sintaxis. saludos!